# In an apache reverse proxy config, for the max attempts, do balancers count as workers?

Tags: apache, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, failover

Within the [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass) directive is a table titled
*Balancer parameters* and it has a row called *maxattempts*. The default is as follows:

> One less than the number of workers, or 1 with a single worker.

Does each BalancerMember count as a worker or only the Proxy containing them?
Also, how does the balancer know when it is in fact a failed instance and use the other balancer options, say in the next lbset? Is it determined before sending or after a timeout?

As an example, if I have `BalancerMember http://www2.example.com:8080` & `BalancerMember http://spare1.example.com:8080 status=+R`, will the latter only be served after the former is determined to be a failed instance: after maxattempts?

Thank you!